# Disabled select doesn't validate when order is submitted in blade template

Tags: php, laravel-4, laravel-blade

I have this condition in my order.blade

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="shipping_method" class="control-label">Shipping method:</label>
        @if( $total < $free_delivery )

            {{ Form::select('shipping_method', [
                Settings::SETTINGS_SHIPPING_NORMAL => 'Normal Delivery',
                Settings::SETTINGS_SHIPPING_EXPRESS => sprintf('Express Delivery - $%.2f', Settings::getOption('express_shipping_cost'))
            ], null, ['class' => 'form-control']) }}
        @else

            {{ Form::select('shipping_method', [
                Settings::SETTINGS_SHIPPING_FREE => 'Free Delivery'
            ], null, ['class' => 'form-control','disabled']) }} 
        @endif       
</div>
```

When user make order for more than X amount he gets free delivery. The problem here is that when I try to submit order with free delivery i.e. in `else` block I've got that `shipping method` is required.

In `IF` block is working. Why doesn't get the name of else block? Here is my validation rule

```
$validatorRules = array(
        'captcha' => 'required|captcha',
        'shipping_method' => 'required|in:' . implode(',', [Settings::SETTINGS_SHIPPING_NORMAL, Settings::SETTINGS_SHIPPING_EXPRESS, Settings::SETTINGS_SHIPPING_FREE])
);
```

Comment: If the element is disabled it is no POST-ed...you can put a hidden element  :)

Comment: Hm, I didn't tough disabled element didn't go in POST.. How can I put hidden element inside `Fofm::select` element

Comment: You can put it outside of the `select` I guess

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In a form if an element is disabled, it's not send with your request, you can enable it since you only have this in your select when shipping is free.
If you really want it disable you can catch when your form is submitted in JS, and the value to and hidden field with the same `name` or just add an hidden field in your form

```
 {{ Form::hidden('shipping_method', /* Params */) }}
 {{ Form::select('shipping_method', [
          Settings::SETTINGS_SHIPPING_FREE => 'Free Delivery'
          ], null, ['class' => 'form-control','disabled']) }}
```

Comment: Ok, thank's for the answer. I want to be disabled and would like to use `hidden` field. Can you show me example how to put hidden field in this select?

Comment: I think if you put it before your select with the name `shipping_method`, it will be posted, added it my main answer

Comment: I've tried like this: `{{ Form::hidden('shipping_method', [ Settings::SETTINGS_SHIPPING_FREE => 'Free Delivery' ]) }}` but I got error `'htmlentities() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given'`

Comment: `{{ Form::hidden('shipping_method', 'Free Delivery') }}`

Comment: Hm.. still doesn't pass validation: `The selected shipping method is invalid.`

Comment: Try to set it after your select, or you can enable your select on validation with JS, this will be invisible for users. But an hidden field should work

Comment: Since you don't really need the select, don't use `shipping_method` as name for it, keep it just for the hidden input. I think that's the issue

Comment: I save this also in database. So in the backend admin will see that is `Free Delivery`.

Comment: The value of `shipping_method` will still be 'Free Delivery` when the form will be submit since it's the value you set in the hidden field, nothing change for your backend

Comment: Seems like doesn't work.. I've removed the name of select and leave the name in the hidden field -> again `The selected shipping method is invalid.`

Comment: The value of the hidden field must be whatever you're waiting, I think in your case it's `Settings::SETTINGS_SHIPPING_FREE` not `Free Delivery`

Comment: Well yes... already tried this `{{ Form::hidden('shipping_method', [ Settings::SETTINGS_SHIPPING_FREE => 'Free Delivery' ]) }}` and got error : `'htmlentities() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given'`

Comment: Because here you're passing an array, but the hidden value is a string you need to do this: `{{ Form::hidden('shipping_method', Settings::SETTINGS_SHIPPING_FREE) }}`

Comment: Finally. Thank you very much!